# How can I have toString() return a multi-line string?

Tags: java, string, return, tostring

I'm working on a program that searches through an array and finds the smallest value and then prints out the time, firstName, and lastName of the runner.

What I need to figure out is how to return the three values on separate lines, something like:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format( firstName + " " +  lastName + " " + Time );
}
```

That's what I have right now

Is there a way to have the three values print out on separate lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
public String toString(){ return String.format( firstName + ".%n " + lastName + ".%n " + Time);
```

Comment: .%n is platform independent for creating new line.

Answer (score 8):

```
String.format("%s%n%s%n%s", firstName, lastName, Time);
```

if you are using format then use the format string with arguments.

- `%s` = String
- `%n` = new line

Answer (score 3):

A new line depends on OS which is defined by `System.getProperty("line.separator");`

So:

```
public String toString() {
       String myEol = System.getProperty("line.separator");  
       return String.format( firstName + myEol +  lastName + myEol + Time);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To print them on different lines, you need to add a "line break", which is either "\n" or "\r\n" depends on the Operating System you are on.

```
public String toString(){
    return String.format( firstName + "\n" +  lastName + "\n" + Time);
```