# Is a multiline toString() output discouraged?

Tags: java

The javase docs state:

```
toString()
```

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a **concise** but **informative** representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

When handling an object with multiple parameters is it good practice to format the output to display nicely formatted in the console? The default eclipse generated implementation concatenates the variables in a single line which gets troublesome to read, needing to scroll back and forth multiple times and does not group the parameters logically.

I would like to format the output inserting line breaks, but have never actually seen someone doing this before. Will I eventually run into issues with loggers or anything else or is it perfectly fine to format the output of toString()the way I want?

Is it better to implement a additional method `toStringPretty()`?

Comment: One reason against multiline toString would be that in a debugger, strings are displayed in a single line anyway.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491801/how-can-i-have-tostring-return-a-multi-line-string/26492080

Comment: @user7294900 I am aware how you to di it. The question is should I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it is not discouraged to avoid producing multi-line string from `toString()`.
as java doc said it should be concise and informative but if you find yourself in a situation where lots of field should be formatted and represented in log file, notice that nobody looks for pretty log. the log should be searchable with regex to facilitate the finding what you are looking for.

What i can suggest you is that instead of formatting multi-line for readability in log file, print your elements in a single line Json format which is both easy to read and search, but if you what to show an output on console to the user it is better off to extract the formatting logic outside of the `toString()`